# ansible host variable not working for file module with content

Tags: ansible

My inventory file looks like below

```
[all]
1.1.1.1 var1=vaule1 app_var2=vaule2
2.2.2.2 var1=vaule3 app_var2=vaule4
```

My task playbook, to create file if not exists and add content using host variable

```
- name: "Creating file_with content"
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path:  "path-tofile/.test.txt"
    state: touch
    content: "app_env=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['var1']"
  register: app_env_status
```

File is created with empty content, can somebody help here, does i am access variable correctly or my task has any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no parameter *content* in the module [*file*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#ansible-builtin-file-module-manage-files-and-file-properties). Having run the task below

```yaml
    - file:
        path: /tmp/test.txt
        state: touch
        content: "{{ var1 }}"
```

you must have seen the error message:

> fatal: ... Unsupported parameters for (file) module: content. ...

Instead of *file*, use the module [*copy*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#ansible-builtin-copy-module-copy-files-to-remote-locations). The task below does the job

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.txt
        content: "{{ var1 }}"
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
└── pb.yml

0 directories, 3 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
test_11 var1=v1 var2=v2
test_13 var1=v3 var2=v4

[test:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_user=root
ansible_become_method=sudo
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
ansible_perl_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/perl
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/test.txt
v1
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_13 cat /tmp/test.txt
v3
```